# Mysql how to order by an ISO duration column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, iso8601

I have a column that stores ISO 8601 durations.
eg:

```
P1D
P1W
P1M
P6M
P1Y
etc
```

I am trying to find a simple way to order by this column ASC

```
SELECT duration FROM durations ORDER BY duration ASC
```

current result:

```
P1D
P1M
P1W
P1Y
P6M
```

Expected result:

```
P1D
P1W
P1M
P6M
P1Y
```

Comment: I've updated the question with the current/expected result

Comment: You'd probably have to parse the string and sort using a case expression, storing data in such a way is not a good fit for an RDBMS

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a case expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE duration   
        WHEN 'P1D' THEN 1
        WHEN 'P1W' THEN 7
        WHEN 'P1M' THEN 30
        WHEN 'P3M' THEN 90
        WHEN 'P6M' THEN 180
        WHEN 'P1Y' THEN 365
        ELSE 999
    END AS duration
FROM durations

ORDER BY duration ASC
```